# Poincare disk and mobius transformation

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I have following problem

---

Consider Poincare disk.

$i.e$ $\mathbb{M}=\{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : x^2+y^2 <1 \}$  with metric 
$ g= 4\frac{dx^2 +dy^2}{(1-x^2-y^2)^2}$

Show the complex mobius transformation, 
\begin{align}
z \rightarrow \frac{z-w}{1-\bar{w}z}
\end{align}understood as a map of $\mathbb{M}$ into itself.

Here one can set as $z=x+iy$, and  $w=a+ib$, where $(x,y) \in \mathbb{M}$ and $(a,b) \in \mathbb{M}$.

---

I don't understand the sentence "a map of $\mathbb{M}$ into itself. "
What does this mean?

---

I try to see $\frac{z-w}{1-\bar{w}z} \in \mathbb{M}$

\begin{align}
z \rightarrow \frac{z-w}{1-\bar{w}z}
\end{align}
with $z=x+iy$, and  $w=a+ib$, where $(x,y) \in \mathbb{M}$ and $(a,b) \in \mathbb{M}$.

\begin{align}
\frac{z-w}{1-\bar{w}z}&=\frac{x+iy-(a+ib)}{1-(a-ib)(x+iy)}=\frac{x-a+i(y-b)}{1-ax-by + i(ay-bx)} \\
&=\frac{x-a+i(y-b)}{1-ax-by + i(ay-bx)} \frac{1-ax-by- i(ay-bx)}{1-ax-by- i(ay-bx)} \\
&= \frac{(x-a)(1-ax-by)+(y-b)(ay-bx)+i[(y-b)(1-ax-by)-(x-a)(ay-bx)]}{(a^2+b^2)x^2 + (a^2 +b^2)y^2 -2ax -2by +1} \\
&=\frac{ay^2 -ax^2 -2bxy +(a^2 +b^2 +1)x -a}{(a^2+b^2)x^2 + (a^2 +b^2)y^2 -2ax -2by +1} + i \frac{bx^2 +by^2 -2axy +(b^2 -a^2 +1)y-b}{(a^2+b^2)x^2 + (a^2 +b^2)y^2 -2ax -2by +1} \\
&=\tilde{a}+i\tilde{b}
\end{align}
Then how can i show $\tilde{a}, \tilde{b}$ is in $\mathbb{M}$?

Comment: "a map of M into itself" mean $f(z) \in \mathbb M$ for all $z\in \mathbb M$, where $f$ is the mobius transformation.

Comment: Okay, in that sense, i only to see that $\frac{z-w}{1-\bar{w}z}$ is in $\mathbb{M}$.  I'll try @John, thanks for your comment